# Should this tag be replaced? review queue

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

There are a lot of "general" tags that should maybe be replaced with more descriptive ones. For example, [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view) is often used instead of [android-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-view) or [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) instead of [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

The tags' excerpt usually mentions which tag should be used, but with no success.

A review queue for tags like these might help retag the questions. It is sometimes very easy to find these questions (e.g. tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view) is often wrong).

The queue might show the question and the tags in question, including excerpts.

A such queue could be accessible for any user to "Recommend Change" and to users over 2000 reputation for “Change“ (as they can edit it themselves).

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

What would a "review queue" for tags actually do? When would questions appear in the queue?

When they had specific tags that had been designed as "weak tags"? Why wouldn't this same thing be accomplished by a *search* for all questions with that tag?

When they had tags that were newly-created and are only used on a few questions? Why doesn't the ["new" tab on the Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) adequately serve this function?

You can retag the questions now, it doesn't require a queue. And the retag privilege is already absurdly low, so there'd be no one with access to this queue that doesn't already hold the retag privilege themselves.

If you are seeking the mass destruction of tags, that's a task with significant side-effects and subject to much disagreement. As such, you need to bring those issues up here on Meta for the community to discuss. Follow the examples of these types of questions that already exist.

If you're seeking the *synonymization* of tags (which isn't appropriate in the cases you mentioned, but is sometimes appropriate), then we have a facility for that, too: you can propose tag synonyms on the "tag info" page for the desired master tag. These are then subject to community review and, if they receive the required number of endorsements, will take effect automatically.

Comment: Questions would appear in the queue if they had tag _combinations_ that are marked "weak", e.g. android + view or css + bootstrap. A queue would speed up the process of retagging these questions significantly, as you wouldn't have to search for all specific combinations invidually, open and read the questions and retag, but the whole process would be streamlined as a single page.